# parse a string into tokens in Shopify Liquid

Tags: parsing, shopify, tokenize, liquid

I have the following string ("my_str") in a Shopify metafield:

```
a:3,b:1,c:2,d:2,e:2,f:2
```

The keys are product variant IDs (shortened to a, b, c...) and the numbers are quantities.

I need to parse it into key:value pairs so I can do something like this with it:

```
{% assign my_str = collection.metafields.local.my_metafield %}
{% assign my_map = my_str | parse ???? %}

{% for product in collection.products %}
    {% assign temp_qty = 1 %}
    {% for pair in my_map %}
        {% if pair[0] == product.variants.first.id %}
          {% assign temp_qty = pair[1] %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden"  id="abc-{{ forloop.index0 }}" value=temp_qty />
{% endfor %}
```

I definitely don't know how to parse my_str. I'm also open to suggestions about the best approach overall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Liquid is pretty limited when it comes to creating arrays. The common approach is to use the [`split` string filter](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#split).

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
{% assign my_str = 'a:3,b:1,c:2,d:2,e:2,f:2' %}
{% assign my_arr = my_str | split: ',' %}

{% for pair_str in my_arr %}
  {% assign pair_arr = pair_str | split: ':' %}
  ID: {{ pair_arr[0] }} Qty: {{ pair_arr[1] }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

This blog post is also an interesting read on the topic of Liquid arrays: [Advanced Arrays in Shopify's Liquid](https://kermode.co/2014/advanced-arrays-in-shopify-s-liquid/)